# ChromeDriver ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR despite --ignore-certificate-errors

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run integration tests on a local host (with no HTTPS) using selenium with ChromeDriver.

Chrome requires an https certificate, but from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774235/chromedriver-in-selenium-and-ssl-certificate) question i understand that i can circumvent this using the arg `--ignore-certificate-errors`

I have also added to my capabilities `acceptInsecureCerts`, as this seems like the appropriate course of action ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/acceptInsecureCerts))

The response from the chromedriver is still not what I was expecting:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection app sent an invalid response.
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# make options (principally to ignore certificate)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# add acceptInsecureCerts
capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

print(capabilities) # see below

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor=SELENIUM_HUB,
    desired_capabilities=capabilities
)
print(driver.__dict__) # see further below

app_login_url = 'http://app:8000/accounts/login/'

driver.get(app_login_url)
```

My capabilities:

```
{'acceptInsecureCerts': True,
'browserName': 'chrome',
'goog:chromeOptions': {'args': ['--ignore-certificate-errors'],
                        'extensions': []},
'platform': 'ANY',
'version': ''}
```

Here is my driver info, it looks like only the `acceptInsecureCerts` arg has been taken into account:

```
{'_file_detector': <selenium.webdriver.remote.file_detector.LocalFileDetector object at 0x7fb42bde10f0>,
'_is_remote': True,
'_mobile': <selenium.webdriver.remote.mobile.Mobile object at 0x7fb42bb5e400>,
'_switch_to': <selenium.webdriver.remote.switch_to.SwitchTo object at 0x7fb42bdd4898>,
'capabilities': {'acceptInsecureCerts': True,
                'acceptSslCerts': True,
                'applicationCacheEnabled': False,
                'browserConnectionEnabled': False,
                'browserName': 'chrome',
                'chrome': {'chromedriverVersion': '74.0.3729.6 '
                                                    '(255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29})',
                            'userDataDir': '/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.vc1ZvB'},
                'cssSelectorsEnabled': True,
                'databaseEnabled': False,
                'goog:chromeOptions': {'debuggerAddress': 'localhost:40815'},
                'handlesAlerts': True,
                'hasTouchScreen': False,
                'javascriptEnabled': True,
                'locationContextEnabled': True,
                'mobileEmulationEnabled': False,
                'nativeEvents': True,
                'networkConnectionEnabled': False,
                'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal',
                'platform': 'Linux',
                'proxy': {},
                'rotatable': False,
                'setWindowRect': True,
                'strictFileInteractability': False,
                'takesHeapSnapshot': True,
                'takesScreenshot': True,
                'timeouts': {'implicit': 0,
                            'pageLoad': 300000,
                            'script': 30000},
                'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': 'ignore',
                'version': '74.0.3729.169',
                'webStorageEnabled': True,
                'webdriver.remote.sessionid': '1cf77f237e966bac6ca15d4d9c107423'},
'command_executor': <selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection.RemoteConnection object at 0x7fb42be0cf98>,
'error_handler': <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7fb427d08a20>,
'session_id': '1cf77f237e966bac6ca15d4d9c107423',
'w3c': False}
```

Why am i still seeing the `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error message...

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection app sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session on your localhost.

As you are seeing this issue on your *local host (with no HTTPS)* as per [this comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739#c26) a blind fold solution would be to add the `argument` **`--allow-insecure-localhost`** through `chromeOptions()` as follows:

```
'goog:chromeOptions': {'args': ['--allow-insecure-localhost'],
            'extensions': []}
```

---

However your main issue seems to be with the *capabilities* where you have set `platform` being set s **`ANY`** as follows:

```
{'acceptInsecureCerts': True,
'browserName': 'chrome',
'goog:chromeOptions': {'args': ['--ignore-certificate-errors'],
            'extensions': []},
'platform': 'ANY',
'version': ''}
```

As per [WebDriver - W3C Living Document](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#processing-capabilities) the **platformName** section mentions, the following platform names are in common usage with well-understood semantics and, when matching capabilities, greatest interoperability can be achieved by honoring them as valid synonyms for well-known Operating Systems:

```
Key         System
---         ------
"linux"     Any server or desktop system based upon the Linux kernel.
"mac"       Any version of Apple’s macOS.
"windows"   Any version of Microsoft Windows, including desktop and mobile versions.
```

**Note**:This list is not exhaustive.

When returning capabilities from New Session, it is valid to return a more specific platformName, allowing users to correctly identify the Operating System the WebDriver implementation is running on.

So instead of passing `"platform":"ANY"` within the *desiredCapabilities* object, a more specific `"platform":"linux"` will be more desirable approach.

> You can find a relevant and related discussion in [Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {“desiredCapabilities”:{“browserName”:“chrome”,“platform”:“ANY” with Selenium and PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752626/curl-error-thrown-for-http-post-to-session-with-params-desiredcapabilities/54754378#54754378)

---

Some more information about the *ChromeDriver*, *Chrome* and *Selenium Client* vrsion would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However as per *ChromeDriver* history the following issues related to handling of **certificate errors** were addressed in the last few releases of *ChromeDriver*:

- [Allow handling certificate errors via DevTools](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659662): As the headless chrome cannot show a UI warning for SSL certificate errors a [fix](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/8452ddd64771d3573cd7083f3e6e263cf67fbe1b) was released to expose the errors as DevTools events and control the action to take through a DevTools command.
- [Provide ability to handle certificate errors in Chromedriver/Selenium for headless](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739): Earlier certain [security related options](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Security/) that was controlled via CLI switches in the UI version of Chromium (like `--ignore-certificate-errors`) were silently ignored and can only be set via devtools. So it was necessary to override and handle `certificateError` events on the browser-target DevTools client. A [fix](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/816f01bc8b6a76716b4bd80394d4c4f737211bbc) was released implementing the usage of the new DevTools method to override certificate error handling browser-wide which allowed ignoring certificate errors in headless mode too.
- [Global certificate error handling via DevTools](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792468): Previously DevTools allowed handling certificate errors for individual targets / WebContents, but when a new target was created (e.g. clicking on a target=_blank link), it was not often not possible to send the `Security.enable` / `Security.setOverrideCertificateErrors` commands quickly enough before a navigation is attempted. A [fix](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/790e30ff7ade211a00e051792d687330f90de789) was published with a simpler "ignore all cert errors" mode instead deprecated the old override command in favor of a new `setIgnoreCertificateErrors` command which also exposes the Security domain on the browser target to facilitate applying this override globally for the whole browser.

---

### Conclusion

- Ensure that the following arguments/capabilities are added:

  - `--allow-insecure-localhost`
  - `acceptInsecureCerts`
  - `--ignore-certificate-errors`
- As you are using `'chromedriverVersion': '74.0.3729.6'` ensure that you are also using `'chrome': '74.0'` (as per [ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) Release Notes)
- Ensure that you are using the latest released *Selenium v3.141.59* clients.

Comment: Solid response and seems to be working well- thank you very much for the thorough answer

Answer (score 4):

According to [Fix "Aw, Snap!" page crashes and other page loading errors - Computer - Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en) (expand the "Page loading error codes and issues" section), **Chrome gives `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` for ANY SSL-related error.** This includes:

- certificate errors
- connection parameters negotiation failures (e.g. TLS version and stream encryption to use)
- protocol violations by the peer

Since you can't get any more details from Chrome, opening the page in another app (e.g. Firefox or with [`openssl s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html)) could give you more details on what's happening.

Sniffing packets with e.g. [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org) can show the initial stages of the connection including the negotiation stage; if the server is yours (so you have its private key), you will also be able to [decrypt the encrypted parts](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#Complete_SSL_decryption_walk_through) -- which would give you the full picture.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, I'm no expert on connection parameters negotiation & protocol violations, but we're not experiencing these issues when using firefox, if that is of relevance.  I'll read up on the issues you mention

Comment: If it's not certificate error, most probably, TLS version or encryption mismatch. Chrome is likely to drop older standards support faster than Firefox.

Comment: If Firefox opens it okay, then there are no protocol violations, either -- or it would too print an error, e.g. SSL_ERROR_RE_RECORD_TOO_LONG.

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting the page through `HTTP` and not `HTTPS`.  Chrome will not connect to an insecure `HTTP` server.

This is causing the TLS/SSL negotiation to fail.

You need to make sure your server is running `HTTPS` on TCP port 8000.

With the `--ignore-certificate-errors` option you can generate a self-signed certificate and apply that to the web server.

Then change the url line to use `HTTPS`.

```
app_login_url = 'https://app:8000/accounts/login/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue on MAC, adding chrome option didn’t solve it.

Following workaround solved problem for me:

- Navigate to `/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages/seleniumwire/proxy`
- Double click `ca.crt` file
- In the `Keychain Access` app double click on `Selenium Wire CA` certificate
- Expand the `Trust` Tree
- Select `Always Trust` option from the dropdown
- Authenticate with password

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles on this while searching for the nodejs answer it is similar...

```
import * as chromey from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome.js';
const chromeOptions = new chromey.Options();
chromeOptions.addArguments(
    '--ignore-certificate-errors',
    '--no-sandbox',
    // '--headless',
    'disable-gpu',
);
const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true)
    .build();
```