# How to disable "Mark non-secure origins as non-secure" within selenium tests?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, http, selenium-chromedriver, saucelabs

I am running non http url inside of my tests (so migration to https wont be easy) and because of that I am getting an warning inside of browser.

How to disable "Non secure" warning inside of Chrome during selenium tests?

[image: Not secure address bar]

I've tried to play with arguments but nothing works

```
 args: [
                      'start-maximized',
                      'disable-webgl',
                      'blacklist-webgl',
                      'blacklist-accelerated-compositing',
                      'disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
                      'disable-accelerated-compositing',
                      'disable-accelerated-layers',
                      'disable-accelerated-plugins',
                      'disable-accelerated-video',
                      'disable-accelerated-video-decode',
                      'disable-gpu',
                      'disable-infobars',
                      'test-type',
                      'disable-extensions',
                      'allow-running-insecure-content',
                      'disable-web-security',
                      'ignore-certificate-errors',
                      'ignore-gpu-blacklist',
                      'no-default-browser-check',
                      'no-first-run',
                      'disable-default-apps'
                  ]
```

The issue is that I need to resize windows to 420x800 but because of warning browser can't do that.

Comment: Can you update the question with the snapshot of the `Non secure` warning?

Comment: Does [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457778/chromedriver-err-ssl-protocol-error-despite-ignore-certificate-errors/56504940#56504940) helps you?

Comment: @DebanjanB I saw it. It looks like a solution when you test https with self generated certificate, in my case its just http

Answer (score 2):

### "Not Secure" SSL Error

As per [Fix “Not Secure” SSL Error on Chrome Browser | Remove Warning](https://www.digitbin.com/make-not-secure-site-secure-chrome-fix/) with the release of  *Chrome 68*, Google started showing all the *HTTP* sites as `Not Secure` on Chrome Browser.

---

### Treatment of HTTP pages

[image: HTTP_warning]

This feature can be turned **On** / **Off** by accessing the page at `chrome://flags/#enable-mark-http-as` and setting the following attribute:

- **Mark non-secure origins as non-secure**: Changes the UI treatment for HTTP pages on Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android

  - Default
  - Enabled
  - Enabled (mark as actively dangerous)
  - Enabled (mark with a Non Secure warning and dangerous on form edits)
  - Disabled

---

Using *Selenium* to disable this feature you need to use the *ChromeOption* **`--allow-running-insecure-content`** as follows:

- *Python*:

  ```
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.legislation.vic.gov.au/")
  ```

Comment: Its not working, and if you see in original question I do have 'allow-running-insecure-content',

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for chrome on android devices.  It's a bad idea for companies to tell users what and what they can not look at.  Tech giants like Google have gone too far and the government is letting it happen.