# Enabling AcceptInsecureCertificates in Selenium EdgeDriver options throws an exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, certificate, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Setup is Windows 10 v1903 and Visual Studio 2019 v16.2.2

I've installed the EdgeDriver using the following command:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

I've then created a new .NET Core console app and added the latest Selenium.WebDriver NuGet package (v3.141.0) to it. Then I've added code to Program.cs so that it looks like this:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions { AcceptInsecureCertificates = true };
            new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the console app I get the following error when executing the `new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);` line.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The specified arguments passed to the command are invalid.
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in ********\Program.cs:line 10
```

However if I change the value of `AcceptInsecureCertificates` from `true` to `false` then I get no exception and the browser opens as expected. This feels like a bug but I don't know if it's Selenium or the EdgeDriver that's at fault.

Comment: The version of EdgeHTML I have is 18.18362 but I am unclear as to how I can determine for sure which version of the web driver the code is using. As I stated in the question I have installed the web driver using DISM and so I guess that's what it's using but how can I be sure?

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457778/chromedriver-err-ssl-protocol-error-despite-ignore-certificate-errors/56504940#56504940) helps you?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Microsoft Edge WebDriver document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver), we can see that the W3C WebDriver is still not support at present.

[image]

You could submit the Feedback at the bottom of the [WebDeiver document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver).