# ChromeDriver ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR despite --allow-insecure-localhost

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have Selenium tests where I'm using ChromeDriver to go to `https://localhost:<port>`. The port number in this case is using a self-signed certificate to support HTTPS connection.

However, when ChromeDriver opens and tries to navigate to that localhost address, Chrome gives an error screen ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR as seen in screenshot below.
[image: Chrome error screen]

I did some research and found that adding the switches `--allow-insecure-localhost` and  `--ignore-certificate-errors` to the capabilities object for the WebDriver instance. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457778/chromedriver-err-ssl-protocol-error-despite-ignore-certificate-errors) gave me some ideas. My code for creating the capabilities is:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// Other capabilities here
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
```

Nonetheless, I still get the same error screen when the ChromeDriver instance tries to navigate to localhost.

I'm using ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 and Google Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: @Kik have you resolved the issue? I am encountering the same problem.